# How do i set the primary color for the whole app?

Tags: typescript, react-native, material-ui

How do i set the color for @react-native-material/core [theme](https://www.react-native-material.com/docs/components/text-input)?

I set it up and was able to change the color but i don't want to do that for every component

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do this:

```
const theme: Theme = useTheme();
theme.palette.primary.main = '#3161D1';
```